# Extract users from AD group and add them to Mailbox

Tags: powershell, active-directory, exchange-management-shell

I want to make a powershell script to extract an AD group and add the members to a specific mailbox. In that group is a group that i dont want to extract (doNotExtract). That is what i have so far:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$csv = @"
Mailbox,GroupName
Mailbox1,Group1
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$ExcludedUsers = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "doNotExtract" -Recursive | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

$csv | ForEach-Object {
    $mailbox = $_.Mailbox

    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_.GroupName -Recursive |

    Where-Object { ($ExcludedUsers -notcontains $_.SamAccountName) -and ($_.objectclass -eq 'user') } |
    ForEach-Object {
        Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $mailbox -User $_.SamAccountName -AccessRights FullAccess -InheritanceType All
    }
}
```

In the AD group are the following objects:

```
doNotExtract
User1
User2
```

I then start the script in the exchange management shell. But then it adds only User1 and User2 doesnt gets fullaccess on Mailbox1.

And i cant find the problem in the script...

Comment: obviously user2 is in group donotextract?

Comment: no, user2 is directly in Group1

Comment: and also in group donotextract

Comment: Mmmm sometimes i should just make a break and look at it again :3 As you said "User2" IS in the group "doNotExtract". Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the error was that the User2 was also in the `donotextract` group.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced with Exchange Online that using `SamAccountName` doesn't always work smoothly. Have you tried using `UserPrincipalName` as input for `Add-MailboxPermission` instead of `SamAccountName`?

I was also wondering why you extract members of an AD group and give them full access to a mailbox? Why don't you instead give the AD group itself full access to the mailbox?

Comment: because he doesn't want group inside that group to have access??

Comment: Azure isnt able to import ad groups... So when I want to move exchange to azure I have to do it this way :( But thanks for the tip. I'll try it :)

Answer (score 0):

As @4c74356b41 mentioned User2 was in the group "doNotExtract". It then doesnt adds him to the Mailbox because this group is excluded.